# How to 301 redirect with NginX without adding port number?

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301

I need to 301 redirect the contents of an entire directory to another directory with nginx. While my configuration works, it unfortunatelly also exposes the port number. This is I guess now a side effect since the inbound traffic for the specific domain is handled via HAProxy ACL rules to the 8000 port, while the url itself is port 80.

This is my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen       8000;
    port_in_redirect off;
    location ~* ^/data/dir1/(.*)$ {
            return 301 /data/dir2/$1;
    }
    ...
```

It redirects from URL:
domain.com/data/dir1/...
to:
domain.com:8000/data/dir2/...

How could I get rid of the 8000 inside the URL redirect?

Comment: Have you tried `return 301 http://domain.com/data/dir2/$1;`? I guess HAProxy should proxy to Nginx properly in this case

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome. I will post the solution as an answer to make question complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the absolute URL without port number:

```
return 301 http://domain.com/data/dir2/$1;
```

HAProxy should do the rest.